# Get the command line version of Maple

Tags: macos, command-line, command-line-interface, maple

I am a mac user and I have maple installed on my computer. I can open maple like any other app. However I would like to work in terminal. I googled and
found that I can do that but I need to change some path. It was not well explained. I would really appreciate if someone can help me setting my path.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the source/link?

Comment: If you feel like @acer has helped you and answered your question, consider marking his answer as 'accepted' and upvoting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to adjust the PATH environment variable. Doing so just makes calling the `maple` launch script for the Commandline Interface (aka CLI) a little easier.

Open a terminal window (xterm). Find the `maple` script of your Maple installation. Perhaps it will be located in some directory like `/Library/Frameworks/Maple.framework/Versions/Current/bin/` say. You should be able to run that script in your terminal by running it using the full name, eg. `/Library/Frameworks/Maple.framework/Versions/Current/bin/maple`.

You could also alias the full name (explicit location) to some single short word.

That `maple` script sets everything it needs to run the Maple binaries, etc. You just have to run it (in a terminal).

Or you could make OSX launch a terminal window and call the `maple` script. Doesn't OSX have an automator for adding such things to the Dock? I forget the syntax but could it be something like,

```
open -a "/opt/X11/bin/xterm" --args "-e /Library/Frameworks/Maple.framework/Versions/Current/bin/maple"
```

Comment: Thanks @acer, It worked. But I have to type this long sentence how can I just type "maple" in terminal and it launches. ?

Comment: If your shell is bash then you could add an alias to your `~/.bash_profile` file, using syntax for a line in that file like `alias maple='fullpathtomaplescript'` say. Figure out whether your shell is bash (likely), or tcsh or whatever, and then google will show you much about setting an alias for that shell's sessions. Augmenting your PATH can be done in the same file, but it seems like overkill to augment the PATH just to get at a single name.

Comment: Thanks a ton..Thanks for your time and help.